# What language are apache .htaccess files written in?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know some of the syntax and such, but does the whole of writing Redirect Rules and blocked IP addresses have a NAME? Or is it just known as 'Apache .htaccess code'?

Comment: It isn't code exactly. It is a _syntax_ though, specifying directives which have arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia's page about [`.htaccess`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), the name of the language is a combination of the previous answers/comments to this question.

> ### [Format and language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess)
>
> **`.htaccess`** files are written in the **[Apache Directives](https://alvinalexander.com/unix/edu/UnixSysAdmin/node170.shtml)** variant of the [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (PCRE) language. Learning basic PCRE itself can help in mastering work with these files.
>
> For historical reasons, the format of `.htaccess` files is a limited subset of the **[Apache HTTP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_server)'s global configuration file** ([`httpd.conf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httpd.conf)) even when used with web servers such as [Oracle iPlanet Web Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_iPlanet_Web_Server) and [Zeus Web Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus_Web_Server) which have very different native global configuration files.

Incidentally, "**htaccess**" is short for *"[hypertext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext) access",* and the `.` dot makes it a hidden file in [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) enviroments.

Answer (score 32):

There is no specific name for the syntax as a whole, but they are called [**Directives**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html).

Comment: And if you came to this question looking to highlight said syntax, (for sublime) look for ApacheConf.tmLanguage

Comment: Yes, they are called Directives and there are typically many uses of Regular Expressions in these files as well.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is written in **Apache language**.

Directives is mere a terminology  that Apache uses for the commands in its own configuration files.

Footnotes: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757